# OnPause/ onResume issues with OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am developping on Android 4.3 and I am using OpenGL ES 2.0.
I use GLSurfaceView and everything works find at the begining. But, when I put the application and background and go back to my application I don't see my view anymore....

I saw it's a common problem. I read a lot of solutions on the internet but it can't fix my problem.

Here is my onPause and onResume code : `

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mGLSurfaceView.onResume();

    super.onResume();

    mCamera = Camera.open();        
    mCamera.startPreview();                
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {  
    mGLSurfaceView.onPause();

    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;

    super.onPause();
}`
```

And how I declare my view :

```
        mRenderer = new TextureRenderer(this);
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(mRenderer);
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        mGLSurfaceView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
```

I tried to initialize my view (mGLSurfaceView) to null in onPause and declare it again in onResume but it the same result, it doesn't work.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can solve the problem.

But I notice in function `onResume`, you do not set the surface holder between `Camera.open()` and `startPreview()`.

Maybe add something like `mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);` can solve the problem.

Hope it helps.